# Dynamic Heap Memory Pool

Tags: c

I am using C programming language in Linux platform and my question is how can I know how much I allocated in heap memory and other useful information such as peak usage in the heap memory. Is there a standard C function for this implementation?

Please advice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're working on Linux, I am assuming you're using the GNU C Compiler. A little searching on Google revealed these websites...

[GNU malloc statistics](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc)

[Summary of malloc related functions](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_3.html#SEC31)

...that give information about the heap stats, which hopefully should contain the data you're looking for.

Good luck!